# Why doesn't DelayQueue use PriorityBlockingQueue internally?

Tags: java-8

When I read the source code of [DelayQueue](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.java), I think that `DelayQueue` is just a special case of `PriorityBlockingQueue`, thus `DelayQueue` can be simply implemented by wrapping a `PriorityBlockingQueue` internally.

So here comes my question, why doesn't `DelayQueue` use `PriorityBlockingQueue` internally ? What's the difference between `DelayQueue` and `PriorityBlockingQueue`?

Comment: For a start, a `DelayQueue` has to interact specifically with the `Delayed` interface.

Comment: @soulmachine I'm not sure, but I think there is performance cost when using `PriorityBlockingQueue` internally because they will using two independent locks. so `DelayQueue` using a basic `PriorityQueue` instead for its purpose.

Comment: Which operation would become simpler (to implement), if a `PriorityBlockingQueue` was used instead of `PriorityQueue`?

Answer (score 4):

A `DelayQueue` is an implementation of a `BlockingQueue` where its elements must implement the `Delayed` interface, and can only be removed from the `Queue` after a specific amount of time has passed (the delay).

A `PriorityBlockingQueue` is an implementation of a `BlockingQueue` where an element's delay would play no part in its blocking mechanism.  The elements in a `PriorityBlockingQueue` are prioritized depending on their natural ordering, or a `Comparator` passed to one of its constructors.

Both `Queue`s will block when the user attempts to poll them when they are empty, meaning that the program will not continue until an element is offered to the `Queue`, most likely on a different thread.

You also must note that the elements of a `DelayQueue` are not prioritized via a `Comparator`, but rather via the use of locks and monitors.

A `DelayQueue` **does** use a backing `PriorityQueue`, but it still needs to write its own blocking mechanism, as that implementation differs from a `PriorityBlockingQueue` (which, when blocking, is notified of an offered element which it immediately returns to the caller).

Comment: `DelayQueue` having an important feature which is : **"If no delay has expired there is no head and poll will return null & does not remove the head element from the queue"** and you still not answer the OP why not use `PriorityBlockingQueue` in `DelayQueue` only the different between them.

Comment: @holi-java That's not really something that anyone can answer unless they were apart of the development team for `DelayQueue` back when Java 5 was released.

Comment: Can I view `DelayQueue` as a specialized version of  `PriorityBlockingQueue`? It needs elements to be subclass of `Delayed`

Comment: If you're asking me, you shouldn't view an object as another object unless one inherits the other.